# Golang how to range in pointer array

Tags: arrays, pointers, go

if I have PersonManager struct and it has *[]Person array. I want to range every item in this array. For example

```
manager := *PersonManager

for ii := 0; len(*manager.allPersons); ii++{
    fmt.Println(manager.allPersons[:ii].name)
}
```

for this example, manager variable is pointer and array that in this variable is pointer too. How can I range this items?

Not: I m getting cannot slice manager.allPersons (type *[]Person) error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `range` keyword. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range

```
for i, person := range *manager.allPerson {
    fmt.Println(person.name)
}
```

Note that the compiler will be angry if you don't use the index var `i`. If you don't intend to use it, replace with `_`.

To further explain, your original error was due to the fact that you correctly dereferenced your `*[]Person` the first time, but not inside the `for` loop.

```
fmt.Println(manager.allPersons[:ii].name) // wrong
fmt.Println((*manager.allPersons)[:ii].name) // right
```

Also, given that your `slice` contains `Person` struct **values**, it will have to copy it if you use the optional second value in the `range` expression. Thus, it would be more efficient to keep using just the indexes.

As a suggestion, don't use a `*[]Person`, use `[]*Person`, which is probably what you intended to use anyway. A `slice` is already a pointer value. Using `[]*Person` you don't have to fear a copy by the `range` expression because it is simply a pointer to a `Person` instead of the entire struct.

In fact, unless you either change the type to `[]*Person` or index into the `slice` you won't be able to have changes reflected in the slice because a struct value will be a copy in the `range` loop. See https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range#gotchas but be aware that if the value is a pointer value, this isn't an issue.

Comment: Couple things; the OP has more issues than just the pointer. Also, you declared i in this scope, but don't use it, which would cause a compilation error.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 Left `i` in there so I could explain its use.

Comment: Good call. As a followup (and it's going to sound nitpicky), it's more idiomatic to just use "for i := range *manager.allPerson", In your example, you're going to force Go to create a variable that would never be used. Nitpicky, but just commenting for those in the future to see.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 was just about to address this, as well as explain his original error.

Comment: Cheers, great revised explanation.

Comment: @UmutcanErtürk see my new edits. You will probably run into problems if you do not change `*[]Person` to `[]*Person`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be mixed up by the pointers. You don't need to dereference your pointer anywhere. Something like this should work:

```
for i := 0; i < len(manager); i++ {
    fmt.Println(manager[i].Name)
}
```

GoPlay here:
https://play.golang.org/p/P8wAp4wIGs